#  mojQuery append a div on mouse move

Tags: jquery

I tried to achieve this by something like this :

```
$('div.check').mousemove(function(e){

    // Mouse click + moving logic here
    $('.movestatus').text('mouse moved');
    var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
    $(".chords").text(clientCoords);
    var ap = $("<div>OO</div>");
    ap.offset({ top: e.clientX, left: e.clientY });
    $("div.check").appendTo(ap);
});
```

What is happening when i move the mouse in the div the main div gets dissapeared or on jsfiddle nothing happens.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/nW53h/)

Where have i been going wrong
**Question**: How can i bind jQuery to `.check` such that when i move the mouse it adds a div at the moved position.

Thanks

Comment: in the fiddle you haven't added jQuery lib :)

Comment: .appendTo takes the left side and inserts it into the argument. So you're removing the div.check from the DOM and inserting it inside your new ap div. The ap div itself is not inside the page's dom, so you're effectively killing div.check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `append`, not `appendTo`.  You also need to position absolute and swap the clientX and clientY.

```
 ap.css({ position:"absolute", top: e.clientY, left: e.clientX });
 $("div.check").append(ap);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ubgNH/

Answer (score 0):

Add this for your HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```